# Show that $\int_{0}^{1}\ln{(1+e^t)}dt\approx\frac{1}{4}+\ln{2}.$

Tags: calculus, proof-verification, taylor-expansion

**a)** Let $$f(x)=\int_0^x\ln{(1+e^t)}dt.$$

Find the McLaurin expansion of the second order, with the remainder term on Lagrangian form.

**b)** Show that $$\int_{0}^{1}\ln{(1+e^t)}dt\approx\frac{1}{4}+\ln{2},$$

with an error less than $1/8.$

---

The first sub-problem was easy, just differentiate three times and plug in to the McLaurin formula. I got that $$f(x)=\ln{2}\cdot x +\frac{1}{4}x^2+\frac{e^{\theta x}}{6(1+e^{\theta x})^2}x^3.$$

Using this to show b), I have that

$$\int_{0}^{1}\ln{(1+e^t)}dt\approx\left[\ln{2}\cdot x +\frac{1}{4}x^2+\frac{e^{\theta x}}{6(1+e^{\theta x})^2}x^3\right]_0^1=\ln{2+\frac{1}{4}}+\frac{e^{\theta}}{6(1+e^{\theta})^2}.$$

Here, the difference between what is supposed to be shown and what I have is the last term $e^{\theta}/6(1+e^{\theta})^2.$ This error will attain max value when $\theta=1.$ So I have that

$$\frac{e}{6(1+e)^2}<\frac{e}{6\cdot 8}<\frac{1}{8}.$$

Thus, when using a second order McLaurin expansion, the error can never be greater than $1/8$.

**Questions:**

1. Is this solution correct?
2. Any detail to change in order to improve the mathematical stringency?
3. In my second equation line, I write that the integral is $\approx$, is this correct or should I use plain $=$?

Comment: I would write $$\int_{0}^{1}\ln\left(1+e^{t}\right){\rm d}t=f\left(1\right)=\dots$$

Comment: For 3 I think you can use plain $=$ since the expansion with Lagrange's reminder is exact.

Comment: I think the answer the question 3 depends on your interpretation of the following: are the usages of $=$ and $\approx$ mutually exclusive, or do the instances in which one can use $=$ form a subset of the instances in which $\approx$ is used?

Comment: @Gribouillis - Yes, $\theta = 1$ is correct! But then the error becomes $1/24$, not $1/30$ as you suggested?

Comment: Yes that's right. But why is that important, if I've already shown that the error is smallern than $1/8$?

Comment: I believe the error is $\max$ when $\theta = 0$?

Comment: Sorry you are correct, the maximum error is $1/24$ and it is reached when $\theta = 0$. But the expression should be $\frac{1}{6(1+1)^2}$ instead of $\frac{e}{6(1+e)^2}$. One can differentiate $\frac{e^\theta}{6 (1+e^{\theta})^2}$ to prove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $f(0) = 0$ by definition and $f'(x) = \ln(1+e^x)$ by the FTOC. Therefore

$$ f(x) = f(0) + f'(0)x + f''(0)\frac{x^2}{2} + O(x^3) = x \ln 2 + \frac{x^2}{4} + O(x^3) $$

The definite integral is given by $$ f(1) \approx \ln 2 + \frac14$$

For the error term we have
$$ \left|f(x) - x\ln 2 - \frac{x^2}{4} \right| \le M\frac{x^3}{3!} $$

where $M$ is an upper bound for $|f'''(x)|$ where

$$ f'''(x) = \frac{e^x}{(1+e^x)^2} $$

This is a decreasing function in $[0,1]$ (you can check for yourself). Therefore $f'''(x) \le f'''(0) = \dfrac{1}{4}$ and
$$ \left|f(1) -\ln 2 - \frac{1}{4} \right| \le \frac{1}{24} $$

Answer (score 0):

Let $g(x) = \log (1+e^x)$ Then $g(0) = \log 2, g'(0) = {1 \over 2}$ and
$g''(x) = {e^x \over (e^x+1)^2}$ and $|g''(x)| \le {1 \over 4}$ for all $x$.

Hence $|g(x)-(\log 2 + {1 \over 2} x)| \le {1 \over 4} {1 \over 2!} x^2$.

Since $\int_0^1 {1 \over 4} {1 \over 2!} x^2 dx = {1 \over 4!}$, we have
$|f(x) - ((\log 2) x - {1 \over 4} x^2)|\le {1 \over 24} $.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach for **b)**:
$$\begin{eqnarray*} \int_{0}^{1}\log(1+e^t)\,dt &=& \int_{0}^{1}\frac{t}{2}+\log(2)+\log\left(\cosh\frac{t}{2}\right)\,dt\\&=& \frac{1}{4}+\log(2)+\int_{0}^{1}\log\cosh\frac{t}{2}\,dt\end{eqnarray*}$$
the last integral is clearly positive, but due to Jensen's inequality
$$\int_{0}^{1}\log\cosh\frac{t}{2}\,dt \leq\log\left(2\sinh\frac{1}{2}\right)<\color{red}{\frac{1}{24}}.$$